# Is "New rules are adhere to" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Today I learned several vocabs including "adhere to".

Also the teacher said that "New rules are adhere to" is also grammatically correct and used normally.

However, I think that it feels weird to me because it ends with preposition "to".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure the teacher didn't *say* "New rules are adhered to"? The final **d** may be almost inaudible before the following **t**.

Comment: See [When is it appropriate to end a sentence with a preposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/16/2303).

Comment: Vocabs? You're better off saying new words.

Answer (score 5):

*Adhere* as in *adhere to* is what’s known a [prepositional verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs#phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs__79)—an intransitive verb that appears with a particular preposition along with the preposition’s object.

Prepositional verbs, unlike other intransitive verbs, can be used in passive voice constructions—like your example.

In the active voice, we might say:

> *We adhere to new rules.*

In the passive voice that would be:

> *New rules are adhered to.* (Note the past participle form of *adhere* here.)

You can see that the preposition must stay next to its verb, while the preposition’s object assumes the subject position in the sentence.

So, among the many reasons not to worry about ending a sentence with a prepostion, this is a good one.

Here’s a big list of prepositional verbs: https://linguisticsgirl.com/prepositional-verb-dictionary/.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides the conjugation of the verb: adhere.

It teaches you all its forms and tenses. I hope it is a helpful tool for you, and enhances your knowledge of the English language while learning new vocabulary words!

https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-adhere.html

Comment: Answers on this site should be self-contained; while this is a useful resource, you should perhaps add the relevant conjugations/explanations to illustrate to the OP what particular rule is at play.